# Redis list performance metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am using redis-queue gem to implement a message queue in redis server.
Every single message undergoes the lpush and lpop command in the message queue.
I am able to get the current length of the queue which is apparently a Redis list using the llen command.

But is there any single way I can get the total number of lpush as well as lpop happened on the list during a particular time span, say in the past 24 hrs. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like [you can use Redis keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) for this. Redis can be activated to publish messages when keys are changed under certain conditions and then you can subscribe to this messages using regular [Redis *pubsub*.](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

Comment: Thanks Matias, Read through Redis keyspace notification and I think it will solve the issue. Couldn't try it out as we are working on an older version of Redis.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using keyspace notifications, as proposed by my esteemed SO peer Matias, there are at least two additional ways that you can do that:

1. The `INFO COMMANDSTATS` prints, for each command, a wealth of information including a counter. To reset the instance's statistics, use `CONFIG RESETSTAT`. Note that this does not offer per key counts but per command (which may be good enough, depending on the case).
2. You can `MONITOR` a Redis instance to get a stream of all the commands it executes. Simple filtering can get you any statistic you're after, but note that using `MONITOR` has a performance impact.

Comment: Hahaha love is in the air!

Comment: Thanks Itamar. I could use INFO COMMANDSTATS to generate another performance metrics that is not specific on keys.